# Leave short lambda used as a middle argument for a function intact using clang-format

Tags: c++, lambda, clang-format

I would like to format the code with clang-format and leave lambda used as a middle function argument intact (as is):

```
void f()
{
    func(0, [] {}, 0);
}
```

Everything I was trying in clang-format 9.0 (and 11.0.0-2663a25f as well) wraps arguments to the next line, i.e.:

```
void f()
{
    func(
        0, [] {}, 0); // not-ok
}
```

If there is no first or/and last argument even built-in `-style='WebKit'` option gives desired results:

```
void f()
{
    func([] {}, 0); // ok
    func(0, [] {}); // ok 
    func([] {});    // ok 
}
```

It seems that something changed (broken) since LLVM 8.0, because 7.1 works as needed. I.e. gives me the same as I had originally:

```
void f()
{
    func(0, [] {}, 0); // how to achieve this after clang-format?
}
```

Comment: `// clang-format off` ?

Comment: @SergeyA :) off is not an option, since I need column limit in general.

Comment: Btw, to trigger this bug, all you need is this: `func(0, [] {}, 0);`

Comment: OK, I reported it here: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45141

Comment: I encountered this as well today. It was reported in Bugzilla two other times: 45424 and 28546. Nothing seems to be happening.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of `clang-format` (that is 10) has configuration options specific to formatting lambdas. Specifically what you are asking for can be achieved by assigning to the configuration directive `AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine` the value `SLS_Inline`.

Following are the other options available from the [offical documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

> **AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine** `(ShortLambdaStyle)`
>
> Dependent on the value, auto lambda  { return 0; } can be put on a single line.
>
> Possible values:
>
> `SLS_None` (in configuration: None) Never merge lambdas into a single line.
>
> `SLS_Empty` (in configuration: Empty) Only merge empty lambdas.

```
auto lambda = [](int a) {}
auto lambda2 = [](int a) {
    return a;
};
```

> `SLS_Inline` (in configuration: Inline) Merge lambda into a single line if argument of a function.

```
auto lambda = [](int a) {
    return a;
};
sort(a.begin(), a.end(), ()[] { return x < y; })
```

> `SLS_All` (in configuration: All) Merge all lambdas fitting on a single line.

```
auto lambda = [](int a) {}
auto lambda2 = [](int a) { return a; };
```

I didn't find a way to do the same on the `clang-format` shipped with `LLVM 8`. The closest configuration I found was the following

```
clang-format -style={BasedOnStyle: WebKit, AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: true,  AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true}
```

Anyway it does not achieve your full request, this is how it looks on my Windows laptop:

```
void f() {
  func([this] { return false; },
       this);                           // ok
  func(this, [this] { return false; }); // ok
  func([this] { return false; });       // ok
}
```

Comment: Just for reference: `AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine` is available even in `clang-format 9.0.0`

Comment: My question's main issue was in using lambda as a middle argument of the function. I don't see any examples in your code about such case.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ as you may see the `sort` function call in the second code block of my answer uses a `short lambda` as third argument. I'm not aware of the fact that there is any difference between the middle argument (i.e. the second one in a three argument function) and others; they'll be treated the same way unless otherwise specified. This is also explicitly stated in the doc for the `BinPackArguments` configuration option, that performs alignment of arguments at function call site either all on the same line or each on is own line.

Comment: Yes, this is not a solution. The problem is actually a bug in clang-format as noted above.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the problem at all and shouldn't have been awarded a bounty.