# Which LLVM release will contain the specific issue closed on GitHub?

Tags: github, llvm, clang-format

For instance, there is a recently [closed issue](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44486) on LLVM GitHub repository related to clang-format. Question about the issue was posted on Stack Overflow as well: [Leave short lambda used as a middle argument for a function intact using clang-format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57153594/3240681)

How I can determine which upcoming LLVM release will contain that fix?

I've looked through the linked page from GitHub https://reviews.llvm.org/D156259 but didn't find a mention about potential further release versions that may contain the fix.

Comment: See the Release Timeline https://llvm.org/docs/HowToReleaseLLVM.html

Comment: The code was committed at some point. `git branch --contains` will tell you which branches contain that commit, and the names of the branches contain the release. If it's in main and there is no branch for a release yet, then you may assume that the commit will be in that release.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a commit hash from Phabricator and go to GitHub you can find out what branches contain it: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/d06b923915137c86e9f281e7fce28240e13665ea

It seems that this change didn't get into any release yet nor it was cherry-picked somewhere.

Here is an example of a change that ended up being cherry-picked into a release branch (see all the rc tags): https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/488a4b24817ae7d9319d8a99bd96c491b2035641

Comment: Do you mean that we have to wait when the interested commit will be a part of some named branch [like other one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0uuA.png)?

Comment: The new major release branch will be created from `main`, so the next major LLVM release will surely contain this change. As for patch releases - yes, you need to watch tags and cherry-picks. If the commit isn't cherry-picked anywhere, it will not appear in patch releases.